# Pushing Data From Arduino To Firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, arduino, gps, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to push data from Arduino/esp8266 to firebase use (Firebase.pushString()) command but it keeps creating a new reference key with every push how could I push data without reference key?
here's my code example

Firebase.pushString("/Data/Longitude", longi );

here is screenshot of data

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`pushString()` will return an unique key you should use `setString()` command to set data without key.
But `setString()` will set the same data everytime so you will not get multiple result as your screenshot so the easiest way to get multiple data using `setString()` is to declare a new variable with a string type and make it inside a loop function because we need this variable to change the value everytime ,i will give you a simple exemple to understand:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      String k = String(i); 

      Firebase.setString("/something/something again/"+k,value);
```

I hope this help you 
Your friend from Tunisia nice to meet you